# setup.py dependency_links Pypi name conflict

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, pypi

I have a non-Pypi package that I want to install using `setup.py` file, so I include it in the `dependency_links`:

```
dependency_link=['package_url.tar.gz']
```

The problem there's another package with the same name on Pypi, so the `setup.py` just ignores my `dependency_links` line and installs that. Is there a way around this?